# Memory climbs but without any memory leak in code, happens in iPhone 3G, SDK 3.0

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, memory-leaks

I found that memory kept growing without any memory allocated in code when running a opengles based program on iPhone 3G device.

Copy from Instrument:

```
    Instances / Responsible / Responsible Caller
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    GeneralBlock-8 / QuartzCore / x_list_prepend_
    GeneralBlock-56 / QuartzCore / CAImageQueueCollect
```

Here's the link about the same problem, [link](http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/cocos2d-iphone-discuss@googlegroups.com/msg06508.html).

Is there any way to fix it or just leave it alone?

Thank you.

Comment: This won't happen on iOS 3.2 and iOS 4.0 (tested)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue but then I realized that the tool doesn't show any leaks though there are some leaks.

Like in the following case:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *arr;
self.arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

In dealloc:

```
[self.arr release];
```

This is a leak which is not predicted by tools.

When the array is created it comes with retain count of 1 and when you use setter method using self it increases it to two. But you are just releasing it once.

So the right way of doing it is:

```
NSMutableArray *tempArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.arr = tempArr;
[tempArr release];
```

In dealloc:

```
[self.arr release];
```

See if this issue can resolve your problem.

Comment: or:
NSMutableArray *tempArr = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]autorelease];
self.arr = tempArr;